# Database not selected php 5.3

Tags: php, singleton, database-connection

I have a kind of connection that worked correctly in php 5.2, but now un updating to version 5.3 and it generates the error: "Database not selected". This is my script:

config.php :

```
$host = 'localhost'
$user = 'root'
$password = ''
$db = 'mydb'
```

Conf.class.php :

```
class Conf{

    private $_userdb;    
    private $_passdb;    
    private $_hostdb;    
    private $_db;     
    static $_instance;

    private function __construct(){
               require 'config.php';  
           $this->_userdb=$user;       
           $this->_passdb=$password;       
           $this->_hostdb=$host;       
           $this->_db=$db;
    } 

    private function __clone(){ }

    public static function getInstance(){
            if (!(self::$_instance instanceof self)){          
                self::$_instance=new self();
            }       
            return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function getUserDB(){
            $var=$this->_userdb;       
            return $var;    
    }

    public function getHostDB(){
            $var=$this->_hostdb;       
            return $var;    
    }     
    public function getPassDB(){
            $var=$this->_passdb;       
            return $var;    
    } 

    public function getDB(){
            $var=$this->_db;       
            return $var;    
    } 
}
```

Db.class.php :

```
class Db {
     private $server;    
     private $user;    
     private $password;    
     private $data_base;  
     private $link;
     private $result;    
     static $_instance; 


     private function __construct() {
            $this->setConnection();       
        $this->connect();
        $this->result = null;
     }

     private function setConnection() {
            $conf = Conf::getInstance();       
        $this->server = $conf->getHostDB();       
        $this->data_base = $conf->getDB();       
        $this->user = $conf->getUserDB();      
        $this->password = $conf->getPassDB();
     }

     private function __clone(){ }

     public static function getInstance() {

            if (!(self::$_instance instanceof self)){
                      self::$_instance=new self();       
            }          return self::$_instance;

     } 


         private function connect() {

            $link=mysql_connect($this->server, $this->user, $this->password); 
            if ($link){      
                mysql_select_db($this->data_base,$link);
            } 
            if (!$link){        
                die('Can not connect');
            }else{
                $this->link = $link;    
            } 

     }
}
```

Apparently Db.class class, does not operate the function getInstance () because no gets the data from Conf.class.

I need to change something in Db.class and Conf.class?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a copy/paste issue but your db construct calls setConnection while your method name is setConexion.  You also left out the semi colons in your config file.

Otherwise, your code ran fine for me.  Might consider adding an error_reporting(E_ALL); and testing from the command line.  You probably have an include file path issue and you are just not seeing the errors.